# Schedule cleaning on Epson WF-7620 printer

Tags: printing, printer, epson-workforce

We have 5x Epson Workforce WF-7620 printers.

They seem to have an issue where after about 1000 prints they need repeated cleaning of the heads, this usually consists of about 10-15 repeated cleans to get the print head check pattern to work.

This is quite tedious, as someone literally has to stand by the printer and hit clean, wait 5 minutes for it to run, then repeat 15 times.

Is there a way i can either schedule cleaning eg. clean once a week at 3am ?

Or is there a way when i need to be cleaned to set a repeated clean. eg. clean 15 times back to back with just one button push by the user so someone dosnt have to stand by the machine for ages ?

My main machine is running OSX, so was hoping to be able to administer this task either through the in built settings menu on the printer, or via the OSX printer driver or via the web GUI for the printer. Alternatively i do have a secondary windows machine i could run the task from.

Answer (score 3):

There is a software provided by Epson which lets you start the cleaning process from your computer but I don't think you can schedule or run them continuously. Head cleaning utility guide:

https://www.epson.co.uk/viewcon/corporatesite/products/mainunits/faq/1701/12556

Epson doesn't recommend running the cleaning more than 4-6 times, it also wastes a lot of ink.

Comment: You could try to run a scheduled task of a utility that emulates mouse clicks...

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not possible.

As you need to run these cleans multiple times, until the printer is working correctly again, no software utility can accomplish this - unless it is able to run the cleaning cycle, do the test print **and examine it**. That is only possible if the utility could somehow feed the test print back in to the ADF, scan it and check it. In other words, it needs both hardware and software.

Why not invest in lasers instead of inkjets? You'll save both money and hassles.